# viewDidLoad becomes an infinite loop. HELP

Tags: iphone, objective-c, xcode, loops, viewdidload

This is probably the easiest/lamest question.

So I am trying to initialize an array with values 0 to 3 increments of 0.25 in the viewDidLoad method, and I can see an infinite loop here.

```
NSArray *pickArray3 = [[NSMutableArray alloc] init];
int i = 0;
//for(i = 0.25; i<=3; i=i+0.25) 
while (i<3)
{ 
//NSString *myString = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%d", i]; 
    i=i+0.25;
    NSLog(@"The Value of i is %d", i );
//[pickArray3 addObject:myString]; // Add the string to the tableViewArray.
 }
NSLog(@"I am out of the loop now");
self.doseAmount=pickArray3;
[pickArray3 release];
```

And This is the Output.

```
   2011-06-01 11:49:30.089 Tab[9837:207] The Value of i is 0
   2011-06-01 11:49:30.090 Tab[9837:207] The Value of i is 0
   2011-06-01 11:49:30.091 Tab[9837:207] The Value of i is 0
   2011-06-01 11:49:30.092 Tab[9837:207] The Value of i is 0
   // And this goes on //   
   // I am out of the loop now does not get printed //
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your i is an integer, it will never increment adding 0.25.  Use a float or double.

```
**float** i = 0;
//for(i = 0.25; i<=3; i=i+0.25) 
while (i<3)
{ 
//NSString *myString = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"**%f**", i]; 
    i=i+0.25;
    NSLog(@"The Value of i is **%f**", i );
//[pickArray3 addObject:myString]; // Add the string to the tableViewArray.
 }
```

Comment: @Siddharth Iyer : Could you help me with my most recent question if possible ?

Answer (score 0):

i is an int. Therefore `0+0.25 = 0`.

Answer (score 0):

use `float` instead of `int` .

because every time the expression value i+0.25 => (0 + 0.25 ) => 0.25.

```
i = i+0.25;
```

Now you are assigning the value 0.25 to integer **therefore** it become 0 every time and condition in `while`  will never be false with 0 , So it goes to **infinite loop**.

So your code must be

```
float i = 0;
//for(i = 0.25; i<=3; i=i+0.25) 
while (i<3)
{ 
//NSString *myString = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%d", i]; 
    i=i+0.25;
    NSLog(@"The Value of i is %f", i );
//[pickArray3 addObject:myString]; // Add the string to the tableViewArray.
 }
```